# What is MIME-type data?

Tags: java, android, mime

I was reading article about `intents` and i have encountered word `MIME`.
In android-documentation I couldn't find clear explanation about what is `mime-type`.
 *From documentation*:

**type** -- Specifies an explicit type (a MIME type) of the intent data. Normally the type is inferred from the data itself. By setting this attribute, you disable that evaluation and force an explicit type.

1) What exactly is MIME 
2) Why exactly do we need them ?
3) How can it be inferred from `Uri` ?

P.S. Do not link me to documentation, I have read it. Thanks.

Comment: Also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type

Comment: Please do some Google search before you post a question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) stands for Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions.
Is used to determine file type (basically extension) in internet communication.

We need them as a metadata for example for browser to convert bytes received from server to proper file extension.
[Here is list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) like for example `image/gif` convert received data to `.gif` extension

You can extract mime type from request/response header. [Content-type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) `Content-Type: image/gif`. You can also request some specific mime type by `Accept` http request attribute where you specify requested `mime type`. If server fails to convert your data to requested `mime type` it will respond with [406 Not Acceptable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) error code.

Answer (score 0):

MIME stands for Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions, and is commonly used to define the data-type when transferring data across the internet. For intance, "application/json" or "application/pdf" or "text/plain".

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "inferred from `Uri`", but here's how I recently used it in a Xamarin.Android snippet to email a PDF file:

```
UriBuilder ub = new UriBuilder();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
intent.SetType("application/pdf");
intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraEmail, new String[] { EMAIL } );
intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("file:///" + path));
intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject, "Notification: " + System.DateTime.Now);
intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, "There is a new notification.");
StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select mailclient"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Hmm from tag explanation..

1)2)Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions (MIME) is an Internet standard that extends the format of email to support: text in character sets other than ASCII, non-text attachments, message bodies with multiple parts, and header information in non-ASCII character sets

3) Dunno

But this still can be not clear enough then head to [Viki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME)